# Django testing if a view return 404 before reversing it

Tags: django

In my urls.py I have the following:

```
url(r'^foo/', FooView.as_view(), name='foo_name'),
```

FooView may return a 404

so before I do use :

```
url = reverse('foo_name', args=(,))
```

I would like to be sure that the view doesn't return a 404.

How can I do that, is there any way to check with `resolve` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) demonstrate this as an example. You need to reverse the url first, then you can resolve the url to get the callable for the view, and run the view to see whether it raises 404. Be careful if the view has an affect (e.g. changes data in the db), since the code will actually run the view.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def myview(request):
    url = reverse('foo_name', args=(,))

    view, args, kwargs = resolve(url)
    kwargs['request'] = request
    try:
        view(*args, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return HttpResponse("URL did not return 404")
```

Note that this is only testing the url for your current request. A url may return a 404 depending many factors including the time of the request, the logged in user, or request method.

Answer (score 0):

If it is to simply test if there is a match in your urls.py, you could:

```
try:
    url = reverse('foo_name', args=(,))
except NoReverseMatch:
    # do sth
else:
    # do sth else
```

This does not test if the specific view that would be called would eventually return 404.

Reference: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/)

Comment: This is just catching the exception if the `reverse` call fails. The OP wants to test whether the resulting URL exists or would return 404.